# Audio Recorder records low-pitched voice

Tags: sound, mp3

I'm using [Audio Recorder](https://launchpad.net/~osmoma/+archive/ubuntu/audio-recorder) to record a Skype Voicemail. No matter which format and frequency I choose, the recorded voice is too low-pitched afterwards.

Is this a known problem and is there a way to avoid it?

Update: I'm using Audio Recorder version 1.4-2 and Linux Mint Cinnamon 32 bit.

Comment: It will be useful to know what version of Ubuntu you've got.

Comment: Good idea, I've included it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you get a proper answer to this, you might have to work around the problem.

A very easy way to do this is to [adjust the audio files](https://superuser.com/a/519765/315715) produced by Audio Recorder by using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

Open a console and go to the directory where your audio files are stored. Then run:

```
sox my_audio.ogg my_audio_faster.ogg speed 1.1
```

I've found that `1.1` is about right for this particular problem, but you will have to play around to get it just right for you.

Comment: I did something similar with Audacity (Effects -> Change Pitch, 5 %)